# Wordpress custom jquery not found

Tags: theme-development, themes, jquery

I have a custom jquery file, here is code:

```
/* Custom JS */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#top-menu li:first-child a").addClass('selected');
});
```

And here my code to load js file in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_scripts');

function load_custom_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', THEMEROOT.'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), true);
}
```

But when i check with firebug, my js not found. Hope anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run following in your terminal:

```
chmod 0644 /path/to/your/theme/js/common.js
```

This command has to give your file proper rights and your web server will be able to read it.

Comment: i'm build on localhost

Comment: Do you use Windows? You need to check your file permissions.

Comment: i can use another wordpress theme, but when i'm building my own theme i get this problem?